# Yii dropDownList default value

Tags: php, yii

I have this code:

```
echo $form->dropDownList($model, 
                 'defaultPrinterId', 
                  CHtml::listData(Printer::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name'), 
                  array('prompt' => '-- None--'));
```

Which gives me a dropdown list like this:

```
<select id="LabelType_defaultPrinterId" name="LabelType[defaultPrinterId]">
    <option value="">-- None --</option>
</select>
```

However, when the form posts, it adds a value to my table where the defaultPrinterId is 0.  Instead of that, how would I make it null, since it's a nullable field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your controller, after you load the attributes from `$_POST` do a

`$model->defaultPrinterId = $model->defaultPrinterId ? $model->defaultPrinterId : null;`

This changes `0` to `null` otherwise leaves it unmodified.

Comment: This works like a charm, however it seems a little bit clunky to me.  Basically every controller action that uses this needs to have this repeated code to transform empty string into null.  Seems like this should be somehow specified in the model, or preferably one of the parameters on that htmlDropDown tool would send a hint to the model that hey, treat this empty string as null.

Comment: You could also try the `empty` parameter instead of `prompt` but IIRC it behaves similarly.

Comment: Also, if you want to complicate things a bit, you can define custom rules and/or default values for different scenarios (insert/update/etc). Take a look at [CModel::rules()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel/#rules-detail) for more info.

Comment: That's a great idea.  Sounds like using rules is probably closest to what I want to do.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to follow strictly the MVC, validation of values related to the model should be done in, well, the model.

It can be done with something like this:

```
/**
 * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
 */
public function rules() {
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        //rules rules rules...
        array('defaultPrinterId', 'default', 'setOnEmpty' => true, 'value' => NULL),
        //rest of the rules
    );
}
```